# i want to call googleapi snap-to-road but failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I Reference searched program and use two function call googleapi snap-to-road but get IOException,i don't konw how fix this

I visited this 
website(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) and follow this way

```
private String buildRequestUrl(List<LatLng> trackPoints) {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
        url.append("https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=");

        for (LatLng trackPoint : trackPoints) {
            url.append(String.format("%8.5f", trackPoint.latitude));
            url.append(",");
            url.append(String.format("%8.5f", trackPoint.longitude));
            url.append("|");
        }
        url.delete(url.length() - 1, url.length());
        url.append("&interpolate=true");
        url.append("&key=myKey");
        Log.i("brad","url is "+url);
        return url.toString();
    }
```

open Exception i get message

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to add API KEY for authontication in your request.

Comment: @Akshay yes i add my key to this program ，But still this situation

Comment: Go to this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/get-api-key
And create API KEY. add key in your request like you did url.append("&key=myKey"); instead of myKey

Comment: Is that work for you?

Comment: No,I will deal with other issues first,my instructor told me that there are other algorithms that can solve this problem,thank you.

Comment: Please provide alternative answers so others will know other ways to solve problem

Comment: I skipped the question first, so I haven't done it yet.